# Slices of crescent subsequences

Tags: go

I have a slice of float64 containing some values and a float value epsilon, what I would like to do is:

assuming that the slice got already sorted I want to go through the slice of float64 and check that every value of the sequence is bigger than the next one of at least value epsilon.
If it’s not bigger than the value epsilon than we will append on a slice of slices a new slice containing all the numbers read and the next numbers will be put in a new slice until the same condition happens or we finish going through the slice.

INPUT:

```
Epsilon : 0,001 
Slice of floats64: [0,4351 0,455 0,4356 0,4359 0,4362]
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Returned slices: [ 0,4351 0,4355 ] [ 0,4356 0,4359 0,4362 ]
```

This is how I've tried to implement this:

```
for i := 0; i < len(sliceFloat); i++ {
    for j := i + 1; j < len(sliceFloat); j++ {
        if sliceFloat[i] - sliceFloat[j] <= epsilon {
            sliceOfSlices = append(sliceOfSlices, sliceFloat[i:j])
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
}
return sliceOfSlices
```

This is the output that I get:

```
[[0.4351] [0.4351 0.4355] [0.4351 0.4355 0.4356] [0.4351 0.4355 0.4356 0.4359] [0.4355] [0.4355 0.4356] [0.4355 0.4356 0.4359] [0.4356] [0.4356 0.4359] [0.4359]]
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: You're not handling situations where the precedent is smaller. Did you want j - i rather than i - j for the indexing?

Answer (score 1):

The test input you posted is clearly wrong: [GIGO: Garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

```
Epsilon : 0,001 
Slice of floats64: [0,4351 0,455 0,4356 0,4359 0,4362]
```

---

Your code does not attempt to fully implement the specification.

```
else {
    continue
}
```

---

After fixing all the bugs:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func crescents(s []float64, epsilon float64) [][]float64 {
    var ss [][]float64
    for i, f := range s {
        if i == 0 || f <= s[i-1]+epsilon {
            ss = append(ss, []float64(nil))
        }
        ss[len(ss)-1] = append(ss[len(ss)-1], f)
    }
    return ss
}

func main() {
    s := []float64{0.4351, 0.4355, 0.4356, 0.4359, 0.4362}
    epsilon := 0.0001
    ss := crescents(s, epsilon)
    fmt.Println(s, epsilon)
    fmt.Println(ss)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/h-SxeIWPuu-

```
[0.4351 0.4355 0.4356 0.4359 0.4362] 0.0001
[[0.4351 0.4355] [0.4356 0.4359 0.4362]]
```